# Identify/Get the city when the form submits

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

How can I get the city parameters with the form details automatically?

Note: I am using an Oracle database to get the data from the form.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit-form-button").click(function() { submitForm(); });
    });
    function submitForm() {

     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "",
      data: {  
      NAME:   $("#regName").val(), 
      EMAIL:  $("#regEmail").val(), 
      MOBILE: $("#regPhone").val(), 
      NOTE:   $("#NOTE").val(),
      SOURCE: 'MUDON.COM',
      CITY: 'ADD CITY',
      },

      success: function() {
         return false;
      },
      dataType: 'html'
   });


};
</script>

   <!-- You need to ADD CITY VALUE FROM getgeoip function to the CITY Parameter above. -->

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=getgeoip"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getgeoip(json){
        document.write("", json.city);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does "*You need to ADD CITY VALUE FROM getgeoip function to the CITY Parameter above.*" mean anything to you..? if so can you explain what does that mean..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy I would have thought it means that the `city` value from the `getgeoip` function needs to be added to the `city` parameter above. Then again, I'm no linguist.

Comment: @Bluefire "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results" - [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @TilwinJoy There is an attempted solution in the form of code, the user has no idea why it doesn't work (that's why he's asking the question, yeah?), and the expected results are "*You need to ADD CITY VALUE FROM getgeoip function to the CITY Parameter above*", which, as I said, is quite clear in its meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to `http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=getgeoip`, and there is no `city` data there; only `country`, `isp`, et cetera. There's your problem.

EDIT: from the documentation on [telize.com](http://www.telize.com):

```
Please note that the IP location database may not contain all information about a given IP. In this case, only the available data is displayed.
```

So, there actually *is* a city parameter, but it's not always there, and is sometimes undefined. Therefore, you can't rely on it to be useful (then again, that does make sense: you're not always in a city, right?).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in my company we really need the city parameter and found a way.

http://www.famproperties.com/mudon/REST.html

But my concern now is how to get the city/country value to this value CITY:'CITY' to get it saved in my database.